# Python polymmorphic functions with static type checking

Tags: python, types, static, polymorphism

In Python 3.6, is it possible to specify a set of types expected for a specific argument?

For example, suppose I have two classes Point and Dot. I have a function, foo, which takes one argument. I want to use static type checking to make sure the argument passed is either a Point or a Dot. I am looking for something like this:

```
def foo(x: [Point, Dot])
```

but this isn't valid syntax.

I am trying not to create two separate functions for this, and I would like to use static type checking, new to Python 3.6

Comment: It's just not pythonic to check types as it is dynamically typed if you REALLY need a get around I suggest you to check [this](http://blog.mathieu-leplatre.info/python-check-arguments-types.html) out

Comment: Right. I was just wondering if there existed a way to do this with the new static type checking from Python 3.6. The documentation makes no mention of whether checking multiple types for one argument is possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

I understood you correctly, seems like you're looking to use a decorator. For example:

```
@staticmethod
def hi():
    print "hi"
```